# JS: name/val pairs to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, list

I'm using a one-off language similar to javascript in syntax, so an answer in that more common language should suffice.

I have a list of name/val pairs that i built from a big GET string that looks something like

```
"n1=v1,n2=v2..."
```

I'm not sure that my initial approach is correct.  I used a primitive in this language

```
tolist(GETstring,"=")
```

to split the name value pairs into the above list.   Perhaps, this is the wrong approach from the gate.

This gives me

```
data = [["n1","v1"],["n2","v2"],...]
```

I'm trying to change this into a named array, such as

```
data["n1"]="v1";
data["n2"]="v2";
...
```

so that I can access items by name, not by list index (as it is highly volitale)

What is the better approach to getting the data in this format.   I've tried a few including evals but nothing seems to work.

Comment: If ordering is not important (or the data can be sorted later) and the keys all map nicely to strings, use a "normal object" as a Map/Dictionary. Using a loop over the existing data in this case is fairly trivial and there is no need for `eval`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to split the string up then iterate through it.

```
var obj = {};
var originalString = "n1=v1,n2=v2";
var splitOriginalString = originalString.split(",");
for (var i = 0; i < splitOriginalString.length; i++) {
    var tmpObj = splitOriginalString[i].split("=");
    obj[tmpObj[0]] = tmpObj[1];
}
```

Comment: I think you want to use `for (var k = 0; k < splitOriginalString.length; k++)` since you're accessing an array rather than object properties.

Comment: The above code works as expected [http://jsfiddle.net/byYaH/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/byYaH/1/)

Comment: While it works, it's not a great idea. For example, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea (and since it's so easy just to use the other method, why not use it?)

Comment: @Todd, I have updated the answer since the post your referred suggest that when working with arrays in javascript the processor will sometimes get the length wrong. I have yet to experience that result, but as you said, it's easy to use the alternative method so why not use it. Plus using `for(var i =0;...` will perform better if iterating over a large set of data.

Comment: Thanks, i've altered this a bit to fit the language and i have some object pairs now :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to do it. You've got two ways to do `workaround`.

1. Create two arrays, one for keys and one for values.

   ```
   var indexes = ["test", "test2"];
   var values = ["val", "val2"];
   var value = values[indexes.indexOf("test2")]; // will get "val2"
   ```
2. Create nested array with key `0` for your string key and with `1` for its value.